# Display toast message after six months from the date of registration

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to display a toast message in my app after six months from the user's registration date

For example, a user registered on 2018/04/20 i want show toast message on 2018/10/20

that's mean, after 6 months from the date of registration

in php i can use this command `SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` - in sqlite what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

first create a subclass of BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            String key=bundle.getString("MyKey");
            if (key.equals("my_key")){
                Toast.makeText(context, "your message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

then you need to create Calendar and AlarmManager :

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, here insert your mount number "for exam 6 for 6 mount later ");
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("MyKey","my_key");
long futureInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,futureInMillis,pendingIntent);
```

and in manifest add this :

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
```

Comment: انگلیسی نوشتم که شاید به درد بقیه هم بخوره :))
البته به نظر من بهتره به جای "توست" از نوتیفیکیشن استفاده کنی 
و اینکه اگه میخای تستش کنی میتونی به جای `Calendar.MONTH` از `Calendar.SECOND` استفاده کنی

Comment: از نوتیفیکیشن استفاده خواهم کرد این my_key اینا چیه؟

Comment: my_key مقداریه که بعنوان یه ولیو به شیء اینتنت میدی تا بعدا بتونی با مقدار شیء اینتنتی که در رسیور میگیری مقایسه کنی که اگه مثلا انتنت دارای همچین مقداری بود پیغام رو بم نشون بده میتونی هم اصن از اون شرط استفاده نکنی ولی بهتره که استفاده کنی

Comment: پس تاریخ رو کجا استفاده کنم من تاریخ رو بصورت 1396/12/20 تو دیتابیس ثبت کردم حالا میخوام بعد 6 ماه توست رو نمایش بدم

Comment: نوشتم که برات توی خط دوم بعد از Calendar . البته تو کد من تاریخ به شمسی نیست و اگه میخای یا باید تاریخ شمسی خودت رو به میلادی تبدیل کنی بعد ماه رو زیاد کنی یا اینکه از تاریخ شمسی استفاده کنی برای برنامه

Comment: بذار یه توضیح در مورد calendar.add() بدم 
تو متد ادد پارامتر اولش از میلی ثانیه بگیر تا سال میتونی بذاری البته با فرمت خودش و تو پارامتر دومش مقداری که میخای بهش اضاف بشه مثلا چند ماه یا چند روز یا چند ثانیه